# How to make a user control in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am relatively new to the MVC approach so bear with me.  I understand the single model concept in the page.  How would I go about looking a detail element?  Say I have a list of items on the page with the original model.  The list is quite easy to do with MVC and very little programming.  Now, what if I want to look at more detail for one of the items with a click event or url.action in one of the cells?  I would like to display a dialog preventing the user from clicking anything else while the details are displayed.  Would I call a partial view page located in the shared folder and display it in the original page in a DIV?  How can I do that without doing a postback?  Normally, I would do an AJAX request to get the data and fill in the fields of the DIV and then open the dialog.  Can we still do someting like that?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much the same thing. You could do it with or without partial view. So basically, you create a controller method that can serve you the html through partial or usual view. This method would be called through AJAX. Then in your html, attach javascript event to the url, this could be subscribed through JQuery, then in the javascript, call AJAX to call your controller method. Then upon successful, show your detail in list in modal pop up way. Could use any modal pop up thingy too. This is roughly the concept. Sorry if the comment is too long =)

Comment: @Hatjhie yes, I can and have done it this way.  But, from an MVC purest way, what is the way you do it with pure MVC?  Do you make a partial view, like a user control?  How does that get slipped into the original page to display in a dialog?  I have a partial view of the details, how do I place it in the original page, if at all?

Comment: There is no "pure MVC" way... MVC is a more low-level framework, and there are many many many ways to accomplish the same thing, and it largely depends on the way you want to go about it.  Do you want to use Ajax?  Do you want full page reloads?  Do you want to use other frameworks like knockout or angular along with it?  THere's really a lot of flexibility here, which is one of the reasons its so popular.. but it also makes these kind of "what's the right way to do this" so hard to answer.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch  I get what you are saying.  Let's say then that I want to use the normal MVC methods, that is, to send a request through a url.action and then have the controller return with a partial view, which I have defined in the shared folder, which is also a different model than the original page.  DO I have to make one big model that encompasses them both?

Comment: @Dean.DePue - Do you mean you're showing a modal dialog, which you get via an ajax request, then post the data via ajax?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch  Yes, I can it that way, but the bosses here want us to try our best to stay with the MVC way of doing things.  From what I understand, I'd have to make a big model, which included everything I wanted, then do a GET for the particular item and show it in a different part of the page with a partial view, right?  I don't know anything about the ajax action form in MVC, could that work and would it be close to a pure ajax call?

Comment: @Dean.DePue - I've already told you, there is no "MVC way of doing things", there are many ways to accomplish this, and the way you do it depends on what you want to do.  To put this another way, MVC does not provide any way to do what you want to do explicitly, and relies on various third party frameworks such as jQuery, jQueryUI, or others, all of which support multiple ways to retrieve both your HTML and submit your data.